# Issues with my orders controller and search bar

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

I currently have some issues with my orders controller and search bar. 
Indeed, when I write a name, everything's fine and work well. Except that I can write something else after, I have to delete it (first issue).
Then, when I delete what I wrote into the search bar, I raised this error :

```
Couldn't find Place with 'id'= [WHERE "places"."published" = 't']
```

I assumed my search bar is looking for something with no ID, which obviously doesn't exist, but I don't know if my controller nor my javascript is wrong.

Here's my controller :

```
def customer_show
  @customer = User.find(params[:customer_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render layout: false} # Add this line to you respond_to block
  end
end
```

and my JS :

```
:javascript
$('#place_id').on('change', function() {
  this.form.submit()
})
```

If someone have a fix, I would really appreciate ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your code submits the form (performs a search) every time you change the value in the input. So, if you are looking for `car`, it will execute three queries for:

1. c
2. ca
3. car

Then, if you want to search something different, for instance, `bike` it will execute the following queries:

1. ca
2. c
3. 
4. b
5. etc.

The 3rd point is crucial because you are sending an empty string as a search param. Probably, you can replicate this issue by sending empty form manually.

I would suggest adding some logic to the method that handles searching and skip search execution when the empty string was provided.

Comment: Hello @MrShemek, thanks for your answer. But I'm not pretty sure to understand what you suggest me to do. Do I have to add something like `if place_id = nil`?